# Properties of $L^{\infty}$

Tags: definition, lp-spaces

I'm trying to get a better grasp on the idea of $L^{\infty}$. What are the implications if we are given that $f \in L^{\infty}$? 
Also, how do we write $\|f\|_{\infty}$ in terms of the inf of a set of measure $0$? 
And is $L^\infty$ a normed (vector space) because we can define $\|f\|_{\infty}$ on it ( it follows the triangle inequality etc.), but what should we show if we wanted to show $L^\infty$ is a vector space?

Comment: You can set $$\| f \| _\infty : = \inf\big\{ t\geq 0 \, :\, \vert f \vert \leq t \,\, \text{a.e.} \big\} $$  and $L^\infty$ is the set of (equivalence classes) of measurable functions $f$ with $\| f \| _\infty < +\infty$. You may need to check that $\| \cdot \| _\infty$ defines a norm.

Comment: To show something is a vector space, check the axioms for "vector space":  Define addition.  Define scalar multiple.  Check the properties these are supposed to have.